# Handling character / in preg_replace - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace all occurrence of specific terms in a string (or lets say a paragraph).

Those terms can be Blue Restaurant Ocean/Blue Restaurant, Blue's Restaurant.

```
$inputext = "The name is Ocean/Blue Restaurant "; 
$term = "Ocean/Blue Restaurant";
$rule = "/". $term."/i";
$replacetext = "[X]";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
echo $outputext,"\n";
```

**Desired output**

```
 The name is [X]
```

It fails to work when the character '/' is in the input.

My primary goal is to replace all occurrence of a phrase in a paragraph. Is there a generic approach to this using preg_replace?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote)

Comment: Whats the desired result in your case? and a error typo i guess: term must be $term in: $rule = "/". term."/i";

Comment: @Sigma thanks for your feedback. Updated question

Answer (score 2):

Working exmample with escaping by using [preg-quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

```
$inputext = "Those terms can be Blue Restaurant Ocean/Blue Restaurant, Blue's Restaurant."; 

// you put your phrases here, remember to escape
// double quote if you want to use it as phrase
$termList = [
    "Ocean Restaurant",
    "Ocean/Blue Restaurant",
    "Blue Restaurant",
    "Blue's Restaurant",
    "so called \"double quote\" probably",
];

$pattern = '';

$termsCount = count($termList);

for ($i=0; $i<$termsCount; $i++) {
    $item = '(' . preg_quote($termList[$i], '/') . ')';

    if ($i < $termsCount -1) {
        $item .= '|';
    }

    $pattern .= $item;

}

$rule = '/' . $pattern . '/i';
$replacetext = "[X]";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
echo $outputext,"\n";
```

Example using `array_map` and `implode`:

```
$inputext = "Those terms can be Blue Restaurant Ocean/Blue Restaurant, Blue's Restaurant."; 

// you put your phrases here, remember to escape
// double quote if you want to use it as phrase
$termList = [
    "Ocean Restaurant",
    "Ocean/Blue Restaurant",
    "Blue Restaurant",
    "Blue's Restaurant",
    "so called \"double quote\" probably",
];

$esc = function(string $input) : string
{
    return '(' . preg_quote($input, '/') . ')';
};

$termEscapedList = array_map($esc, $termList);
$pattern = implode('|', $termEscapedList);

$rule = '/' . $pattern . '/i';
$replacetext = "[X]";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
echo $outputext,"\n";
```

Comment: $inputext is fed from user inputs and so there is no handle to use escape

Comment: And what if the input is Ocean#Blue Restaurant?

Comment: i updated the answer, now it works with data passed by the user also you have an easy way to add phrases in the future

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte true it isn't :) added more clean code example as suggested

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you should escape characters that are being used as delimiters in regex. Besides, you don't need `preg_*` functions. All you need is [`strtr()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$str = "The name is Ocean/Blue Restaurant Blue Restaurant Blue's Restaurant"; 
echo strtr($str, ["Blue Restaurant" => "[x]", "Ocean/Blue Restaurant" => "[x]", "Blue's Restaurant" => "[x]"]);
```

Output:

```
The name is [x] [x] [x]
```